# Php error in code while updating the data in sql

Tags: php, mysql

I get an error Undefined variable name, address, and id though I have defined it. I have used isset function but it is not working. Also, some HTML code appears in the name and address field.

```
 <?php
$link=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","");
$select=mysqli_select_db($link,'first_db');

if(isset($_POST['update'])){
     $id=$_POST['id'];
     $query="SELECT * FROM list WHERE id='$id'";
     $run=mysqli_query($link,$query);
     $row=mysqli_fetch_array($run);
 }
if(isset($_POST['name'])&& isset($_POST['address'])){
    $name=$_POST['name'];
    $address=$_POST['address'];
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $query="UPDATE list SET name='$name',address='$address' WHERE id='$id'";
    $result=mysqli_query($link,$query);
}
else{
    echo"The fields cannot be empty";
}

?>
```

The HTML code is:

```
  <html>
    <head>    
        <title>Edit Data</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <a href="index.php">Home</a>
        <br/><br/>

        <form name="form1" method="post" action="update.php">
            <table border="0">
                <tr> 
                    <td>Name</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $name;?>"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr> 
                    <td>address</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="address" value="<?php echo $address;?>"></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                   <td><input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $_GET['id'];?>"></td>
                    <td><input type="submit" name="update" value="Update"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: you missed ```$id=$_GET['update'];``` in second if condition. there is no id defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the issue, So I am posting a separate answer here again:

You need to update few things,

```
<?php
$link=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","");
$select=mysqli_select_db($link,'first_db');

if(isset($_GET['update'])){  // Checking if the query parameter is available.
     $id=$_GET['update'];    // Getting the query string value here.
     $query="SELECT * FROM list WHERE id='$id'";
     $run=mysqli_query($link,$query);
     $row=mysqli_fetch_array($run);
 }
if(isset($_POST['name'])&& isset($_POST['address'])){
    $name=$_POST['name'];
    $address=$_POST['address'];
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $query="UPDATE list SET name='".$name."',address='".$address."' WHERE id='".$id."'";  // Added `""` here for all variables.
    $result=mysqli_query($link,$query);
}
else{
    echo"The fields cannot be empty";
}

?>
```

Notice in the above code that you are getting query result in $row variable. So use that in HTML as well. Like this:

```
<html>
<head>    
    <title>Edit Data</title>
</head>

<body>
    <a href="index.php">Home</a>
    <br/><br/>

    <form name="form1" method="post" action="update.php">
        <table border="0">
            <tr> 
                <td>Name</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo (isset($row['name']))? $row['name'] : ''?>"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr> 
                <td>address</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="address" value="<?php echo (isset($row['address']))? $row['address'] : ''?>"></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
               <td><input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo (isset($_GET['id']))? $_GET['id'] : ''?>"></td>
                <td><input type="submit" name="update" value="Update"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please replace below line

```
<td><input type="hidden" name="id" value=<?php echo $_GET['id'];?>></td>
```

by

```
<td><input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $_GET['id'];?>"></td>
```

You missed "" in value attribute.

**Edit:** 
After correction your HTML will be correct and then please check `$id=$_GET['update'];` its not defined I think you need to correct it as `$id=$_POST['id'];`

Comment: He is not using `id` anywhere in the code. So this is not the solution for the problem.

Comment: He is also saying like in error some HTML code appears.

Comment: The reason for HTML code... I have shared. he is missing. Have you checked? Also see my updated answer.

Comment: No the Html code still appears in the name and address field

Comment: I have added it please check it.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_POST['id']))
{
$name=$_POST['name'];
$address=$_POST['address'];
$id = $_POST['id'];
$query="UPDATE list SET name='".$name."',address='".$address."' WHERE id='".$id."'";
$result=mysqli_query($link,$query);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is as below

```
if(isset($_GET['update'])){
         $id=$_POST['id'];//use this insted of $id=$_GET['update'] in your form name of id parameter is id
         $query="SELECT * FROM list WHERE id='$id'";
         $run=mysqli_query($link,$query);
         $row=mysqli_fetch_array($run);
     }


if(isset($_POST['name'])&& isset($_POST['address'])){
        $id=$_POST['id'];
        $name=$_POST['name'];
        $address=$_POST['address'];
        $query="UPDATE list SET name='$name',address='$address' WHERE id='$id'";
        $result=mysqli_query($link,$query);

    }
```

Comment: I am still getting the Undefined variable: name  error in the name and address field in update page

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$link=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","");
$select=mysqli_select_db($link,'first_db');

if(isset($_POST['update'])){
     $id=$_POST['id'];
     $query="SELECT * FROM list WHERE id='$id'";
     $run=mysqli_query($link,$query);
     $row=mysqli_fetch_array($run);
 }
if(isset($_POST['name'])&& isset($_POST['address'])){
    $name=$_POST['name'];
    $address=$_POST['address'];
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $query="UPDATE list SET name='$name',address='$address' WHERE id='$id'";
    $result=mysqli_query($link,$query);
}
else{
    echo"The fields cannot be empty";
}

?>
```

The html code is:

```
<html>
<head>    
    <title>Edit Data</title>
</head>

<body>
    <a href="index.php">Home</a>
    <br/><br/>

    <form name="form1" method="post" action="update.php">
        <table border="0">
            <tr> 
                <td>Name</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $name;?>"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr> 
                <td>address</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="address" value="<?php echo $address;?>"></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
               <td><input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $_GET['id'];?>"></td>
                <td><input type="submit" name="update" value="Update"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Posted the answer yourself?

Comment: This is my edited code but I still get an error in the update page in the name and address field.

Comment: The first `if` condition is in the page which will get data from the list to show on the edit page? And the 2nd `if` condition will be executed when user will submit the form?

Comment: And you have query parameter in URL `update` which is `id` actually?